# Resume Macro after IE Crash or not respond

Tags: vba, selenium, internet-explorer, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I need to get data from website 
I'm using `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` and `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` and fetch data.
I'm using set `IE = Nothing` and `IE.Quit` after fetching each records and creating new instance for each record but macro stops whenever IE stops responding or crashes.
I just want to skip that record whenever IE crash and resume from the next records
is it possible to ignore each popup from IE and resume from next records to fetch the data.

```
For Each Cell In Selection

    URL = Cell.Value
Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        With IE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = True
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy = True
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

        Set Doc = .document
'*Fetch the Elements and Records by using getElementbyid*
End With
Set IE = Nothing
IE.quit
Next Cell
```

I've tried using selenium also but facing same issue.
I just want to ignore if IE crashes or not respond for particular record and fetch the next one.
IE crashes sometime after 2000 records and sometime after 100 records.
I need to run  this macro overnight.
I'm using IE 11 and Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly improve on this but here is a **basic** starting method.

Note that we don't keep creating and destroying instances of IE. We create one and use it to process the various URLs and then close it at the end.

A simple `On Error GoTo Label` is used to handle the failures. The error is then cleared. The label takes the program to the next loop.

It may be possible to introduce a loop with timeout to attempt to set the element i.e. `Do  :  On Error Resume Next : Set a = .document.getElemmentById("id") : On Error GoTo O : Loop While a Is Nothing` but have a time out clause inside the loop to avoid never ending looping.

For the IE is hanging part is it is difficult to say. Perhaps process the URLs in chunks and combined with the time out loop mentioned above where an attempt is made to set an element into a variable?

Overall, ascertain reason for crashes if possible and target your solution to handle that.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim IE As Object, doc As Object
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        Dim currentCell As Range, URL As String
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        On Error GoTo nextURL
        For Each currentCell In Selection
            URL = currentCell.Value
            .navigate URL

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
            Set doc = .document

            'Attempt to getElementByID
nextURL:
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear
            If IE Is Nothing Then Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        Next currentCell
    End With
   IE.Quit
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```